# What object passing option between Android activities is better from performance view?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, performance

I have got application that is using SQLite in it. From those records using cursor there is shown ListActivity for user to choose which object's info he wants to get.

After pressing on it Intent is started with extra long - object id. In target activity of this intent extra is used to get info about object. So what it does, it opens database and using object id get all date.

I've started wondering is it a good option and can I boost performance of my app on it or not? First I was thinking about object putting into parcelable and sending like this, but there is one tricky thing - in ListActivity aren't all fields downloaded which are shown (downloaded) in target activity.

So maybe it would be better to download all available fields from database in ListActivity and then only pass it in extra?

What do you thing? What is the best option, maybe there is something else?

I forget two important I think info: I am using normal SQLite, because I don't need FTS3, and database can have hundreds of records.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say searching element by id in DB should be pretty fast and as you once it once on activity start it should not be performance problem. Meanwhile it's much cleaner approach when activity gets only id and then loads all data by itself. Of course you need to try both way and see if it really gives you performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends.

If all you do is listing the records and then click them to check the details, the second option would be the best and cleaner, as Nikita Beloglazov said. Which I upvoted it, as it is very common.

However, if you intend to do a lot of operations in cascade, I would recommend that instead of reading the data from the db everytime you open an activity, you can pass around the object. In that case, if the list has a lot of records, you can load them asynchronously. Also, if object has a lot of data (even an collection with collections within), you must have in mind that it will increase the memory usage.

In the end, the question is about memory vs I/O operations vs what you need/have.